# SortBy included values in IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm learning more about IQueryable's and have a sorting method:

```
public IQueryable<T> OrderEntities(IQueryable<T> entities, string sortColumn, string sortOrder)
{
    string sort = sortColumn;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        sort += " " + sortOrder;
    }
    return entities.SortBy<T>(sort);
}
```

which works fine, except when my entities query contains a lazy loaded, or included, table that has a property you try to sort on. Is this possible through one of the queryable extensions I see floating around?

Comment: What happens when you have "a lazy loaded, or included, table that has a property you try to sort on"? It is important to remember readers can't run the code in their heads, so it saves time to mention what is going wrong.

Comment: You just have a doubt right? I don't see a question here. If the context is still alive, eager loading will be done, if the context is not alive, null reference might be thrown.

Comment: How is this confusing? It's a simple question, I'm asking if it's possible to sort on a lazy loaded value on a IQueryable<T>. It throws an error saying the value loaded through an Include doesn't exist. If there's more that I need to explain about the scenario I'm happy to provide it, but I think it's perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using magic strings in your linq queries, which, while working in some scenarios, is bad practice in my opinion.

If you really can only get the required ordering by a string, I would suggest you to use a dictionary that maps your allowed magic string to a predicate : `IDictionary<string, Funct<...>`

That way you can have strongly typed, compile time checks, and the flexibility of the strings.
Find your string parameter in the dictionary, and then apply the predicate to your OrderBy clause.

If the requested sorting is not supported, you can use dictionary functions to validate and report a comprehensive message to the user/developer.